# KSOAP2 returning a error while trying to pass a path as a property

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

I have a webservice SOAP, that i want to access by android in my Nexus 4.
When i try to put a String path like a property, im getting a error, soapfault:
The system could not find the specified path (or something like that).

This is the code of the method:

```
public void uploadImage() throws IOException, XmlPullParserException{
    String path = pathImg;
    String name = nomeImg;

    SoapObject soap = new SoapObject(NAME_SPACE,"uploadImage");
    soap.addProperty("pathImg", path);
    soap.addProperty("nameImg", name);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soap);

    Log.i("NGVL", "Chamando UploadImage");


    HttpTransportSE httptransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        httptransport.call(METHOD_UPLOAD_IMAGE, envelope);

        Object msg = envelope.getResponse();

        Log.i("NGVL", "Mensagem:" + msg);


}
```

This is the LogCat:

```
07-17 09:22:12.971: W/System.err(4090): SoapFault - faultcode: 'soapenv:Server' faultstring: '\storage\emulated\0\Pictures\Instagram\IMG_20130716_194320.jpg (The system cannot find the path specified)' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@422e1df0
07-17 09:22:12.971: W/System.err(4090):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(Unknown Source)
07-17 09:22:12.971: W/System.err(4090):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(Unknown Source)
07-17 09:22:12.971: W/System.err(4090):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Unknown Source)
07-17 09:22:12.971: W/System.err(4090):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(Unknown Source)
07-17 09:22:12.971: W/System.err(4090):     at br.ufc.cloud.qnotes.ui.MainActivity.uploadImage(MainActivity.java:107)
07-17 09:22:12.971: W/System.err(4090):     at br.ufc.cloud.qnotes.ui.MainActivity.createNote(MainActivity.java:119)
07-17 09:22:12.971: W/System.err(4090):     at br.ufc.cloud.qnotes.ui.MainActivity$Task.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:204)
07-17 09:22:12.971: W/System.err(4090):     at br.ufc.cloud.qnotes.ui.MainActivity$Task.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-17 09:22:12.971: W/System.err(4090):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-17 09:22:12.971: W/System.err(4090):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-17 09:22:12.971: W/System.err(4090):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-17 09:22:12.971: W/System.err(4090):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-17 09:22:12.971: W/System.err(4090):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-17 09:22:12.971: W/System.err(4090):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: where are logcat logs?

Comment: Edited with the LogCat

Comment: seems like a path is wrong ... check if `new File(pathImg).exists()` is true (should be `"/"` instead `"\"` on android?)

Comment: The path is right...do you think that should be Relative Path?

Comment: no it should not it should be a full path ... but if you are using external storage do you have a permission to read it in manifest? ...

Comment: Yeah...i have the permission. :/

Comment: I'm getting the path by calling an intent that calls gallery and getting the path, from the data. I'm not using Enviroment.GetExternalStorage...